# How to read slices of MNIST dataset in python using tensorflow?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I am using following method to read data from MNIST dataset which get whole MNIST dataset:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("C:/User/Downloads/mnistData", one_hot=True)
```

but I want to train and test my MLP on dataset slice as follows:

```
Training set: the first 5,000 of the original training images and
Testing set: same.
```

How to slice MNIST dataset for this purpose? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(5000)` will give you the first 5000 train examples and their labels.